# Bluebird's Promise.settle doesn't resolve with the correct values

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have the following code:

```
return Promise.settle(matches, imgur.uploadUrl)
    .map(function (inspection) {
        if (inspection.isFulfilled()) {
            return inspection.value().data.link;
        }
        return '#';
    })
```

A more verbose version of the above displays the same problems:

```
return Promise.settle(matches, function(match) { return imgur.uploadUrl(match); })
    .then(function(results) {
        return results;
    })
    .map(function (inspection) {
        if (inspection.isFulfilled()) {
            return inspection.value().data.link;
        }
        return '#';
    })
```

Where

- `Promise` = bluebird's promise
- `matches` = an array of image links extracted from a string
- `imgur` = https://github.com/kaimallea/node-imgur

The expected behavior is that the result of `.map` is a promise which resolves with an array of imgur links after the images in the original array was uploaded to imgur (or '#', in case the upload failed for any reason).

What happens instead is that Promise.settle resolves *instantly* (i.e. doesn't seem to wait for the imgur uploads), and `inspection.value()` is the original image url from the `matches` array (which gives an error when trying to read the `.data.link` property of a string).

Why does this happen? Why won't it upload to imgur and resolve correctly?

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying to `Promise.settle(matches, imgur.uploadUrl).then(function(results) { ... })` first to see if `results` contains what you expect so you can see if it's the `.settle()` not doing what you want or the `.map()`.

Comment: I actually did do that before I got to this exact version of the code, and it didn't do much difference.

Comment: The point of my comment was for you to explain whether just the `.settle()` gets the right results or not?  Is the issue with `.settle()` or with `.map()`.  I'm trying to break a complicated problem down into pieces so one knows where to look further for the issue.

Comment: When I look at the  [Bluebird source](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/settle.js) for `Promise.settle()`, I only see that it processes the first argument (expecting an array of promises).  I wonder if the Bluebird documentation for `.settle()` is just wrong about it taking a function as the second argument that will process the first array?  The code is a little hard to follow, but I don't see how `Promise.settle()` ever uses the 2nd argument (unless this isn't the right code I'm looking at for some reason).

Comment: @jfriend00 Post that as an answer. I refactored to `Promise.settle(matches.map(imgur.uploadUrl))` and it worked. I will file a bug with bluebird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look at the [Bluebird source](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/settle.js) for `Promise.settle()`, I only see that it processes the first argument (expecting an array of promises).  I've always just used it as a substitute for `Promise.all()` when you want all promises to complete, even if some have errors.

I wonder if the Bluebird documentation for `.settle()` is just wrong about it taking a function as the second argument that will process the first array? The code is a little hard to follow, but I don't see how `Promise.settle()` ever uses the 2nd argument (unless this isn't the right code I'm looking at for some reason).

As you pointed out, an alternative is:

```
Promise.settle(matches.map(imgur.uploadUrl)).then(...)
```

which just passes an array of promises to `.settle()`.

---

FYI, I verified by creating a simple test case and stepping into `Promise.settle()` in the debugger that it never uses the second argument passed to it.  This appears to be a case of the documentation not matching the implementation.  I expect someone planned to implement what is documented, but never completed that implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This was indeed a bug in the docs. It was fixed (props to OP for the pull request).

The docs now show the correct usage of `.settle`.

Comment: @andig yep, the new 3.0 way is to `.reflect`.

Comment: Like @andig said `reflect` doesn't exist on Bluebird v3.0.5, but `settle` seems to work.

Comment: @rbarriuso reflect most certainly exists in 3.x

Comment: True. Reflect is the new settle!