# Promise fulfilled inspite of rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I am using bluebird settle method to check results for promises regardless of any rejections. In the **secondMethod**  I have rejected the promise still I get    *isFulfilled()* true.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.settle([firstMethod, secondMethod]).then(function(results){
    console.log(results[0].isFulfilled()); 
    console.log(results[1].isFulfilled()); 
   // console.log(results[1].reason());
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});

    var firstMethod = function() {
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function() {
         resolve({data: '123'});
      }, 2000);
   });
   return promise;
};


var secondMethod = function() {
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function() {
         reject((new Error('fail')));
      }, 2000);
   });
   return promise;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged your code and the code within your functions isn't being called. You need to actually call the functions :)

```
Promise.settle([firstMethod(), secondMethod()]).then(function (results) {
    console.log(results[0].isFulfilled()); // prints "true"
    console.log(results[1].isFulfilled()); // prints "false"
    console.log(results[1].reason()); // prints "fail"
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure `isFulfilled` is referring to if it is complete or not, regardless of if it's `resolved` or `rejected`.

You can use something like [`isRejected`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/isrejected.html) to check to see if the promise has been rejected.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari You are correct. I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594382/bluebirds-promise-settle-doesnt-resolve-with-the-correct-values) now.

Comment: Looks like `.settle` is no longer supported maybe? Docs don't even mention it.

Comment: It's been superseded by `reflect`. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/new-in-bluebird-3.html

Answer (score 1):

`settle` API is been deprecated. Refer the [github](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/931) link and [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4814) for info. Use [`reflect`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html) API instead as pointed in the documentation.

Secondly, [documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html) points out with an example:

> Using `.reflect()` to implement `settleAll` (wait until all promises in an array are either rejected or fulfilled) functionality

```
var promises = [getPromise(), getPromise(), getPromise()];
Promise.all(promises.map(function(promise) {
    return promise.reflect();
})).each(function(inspection) {
    if (inspection.isFulfilled()) {
        console.log("A promise in the array was fulfilled with", inspection.value());
    } else {
        console.error("A promise in the array was rejected with", inspection.reason());
    }
});
```

**Explanation of above code:**

In the above example author is iterating through array of promises using `map` which returns `reflect` and inspecting each promise is `isRejected` or `isFulfilled`.